# Visual Studio 2012 complains about comparing two Brushes

Tags: visual-studio-2012, brushes

Visual Studio 2012 complains about comparing two Brushes:

```
private void SetLabel(string stText, Brushes colorBackground)
{
  if (colorBackGround == Brushes.Yellow)
 ...
}
```

Error message: `"The name 'colorBackGround' does not exist in the current context"`

Comment: you didn't declare colorBackGround or didn't include files/units properly

Comment: `Visual Studio 2012 complains` - your code is wrong. It's not the fault of the IDE S:

Comment: Sorry about the colorBackground typo -> I had fixed it but did not copy it correctly -> too much muxing.  The correct error message is "Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'System.Windows.Media.Brushes' and 'System.Windows.Media.SolidColorBrush'"  I tried changing Brushes colorBackground to SolidColorBrush colorBackground -> it is satisfied with the "if" statement, but does not like gLBl.Background = colorBackGround -> assumed changing it to SolidColorBrush was a mistake.

Answer (score 0):

colorBackGround is not the same as colorBackground! C# is case sensitive